# PHP: Isset with if else statement

Tags: php, sql

**iso.obj.php**

```
$from = null;
$too = null;

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    if ($from = null) {
        $from = date("Y-m-d");
    } else {
        $from = $_POST['FromDateTime'];
    }

    if ($too = null) {
        $too = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days")) . " 23:59:59"; 
    } else {
        $too = $_POST['ToDateTime']." 23:59:59";
    }
}
$sql ="//statement here with
WHERE capDateTime >='{$from}' AND capDateTime <='{$too}'";
```

The code is working fine but i got problem when person request the page and its return an empty table. But if i select date and time manualy its will display according to the date and time.

My question is: How do i put current date if not set and if set follow the $_POST?

Comment: if($from = null){ ??? and `if ($too = null) {` you are assigning the values not comparing

Comment: `if ($from === null) {`  and `if ($too === null) {`

Comment: `if ($too = null)   this ---> =` is an assignment operator. If you want to compare it use `==` comparison operator. [See here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)

Comment: Sidenote: By directly using variables in your $sql, you're exposing yourself to SQL injection. Please use PDO or Mysqli see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: @MaartenSchermer thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$from = date("Y-m-d");
$too = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days")) . " 23:59:59";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['FromDateTime'])) {
        $from = $_POST['FromDateTime'];
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['ToDateTime'])) {
        $from = $_POST['ToDateTime']." 23:59:59";
    }
}
```